# PHP mail function is not working after "from" header is added

Tags: php, html, email

I'm sending email using php header.

```
$to = 'test@email.com';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message = '<h1>Test</h1>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This function is working properly.

But after I added "From" mail() function is not working.

```
$headers .= "From: from@address.com";
```

Any idea?

Comment: it must has `. "\r\n"` at the end

Comment: Try changing the order of the entries with From first then MIME then content type.

Answer (score 0):

May you are trying to spoof email, so it's getting failed.

It would be great practise to keep using **Reply-To** with **From** while using mail()

```
$headers .= "From: from@address.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: from@address.com\r\n";
```

But, personally suggest you to use SMTP instead of mail() or PHPMailer.